sp_executesql is not giving output if use parameters
The following SQL gives me result as 0
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RecordCountInfo INT
SET @ColumnName='EligibilityCategory'
SET @dynamicSQL = N'SELECT @RecordCountInfo= COUNT(*) FROM Students where @ColumnName IS NULL'

EXEC sp_executesql 
                @dynamicSQL , 
                N'@ColumnName  NVARCHAR(MAX), @RecordCountInfo INT OUTPUT' ,
                @ColumnName = @ColumnName,
                @RecordCountInfo=@RecordCountInfo OUTPUT
PRINT @RecordCountInfo

If I use following then it's working. But I have to use parameters here.
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RecordCountInfo INT

SET @ColumnName='EligibilityCategory'
SET @dynamicSQL = N'SELECT @RecordCountInfo= COUNT(*) FROM Students where '+@ColumnName+' IS NULL'

EXEC sp_executesql 
                @dynamicSQL , 
                N'@ColumnName  NVARCHAR(MAX), @RecordCountInfo INT OUTPUT' ,
                @ColumnName = @ColumnName,
                @RecordCountInfo=@RecordCountInfo OUTPUT
PRINT @RecordCountInfo
   


What do you think where @ColumnName IS NULL does exactly? You can't put a parameter in a deferred statement and expect it to behave different to if it wasn't in a deferred statement, As for '+@ColumnName+' IS NULL', I hope you know that a HUGE SQL Injection vulnerability. Imagine is someone said the "Column Name" was 1=1; CREATE LOGIN MyLogin WITH PASSWORD = '123abc!"£'; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER MyLogin; --; what do you think would happen?

The query is wrong to begin with. where @ColumnName IS NULL is false if @ColumnName has a value like EligibilityCategory. You can't specify object names like tables or columns as parameters, only values.
